# Android Studio - Inspect Code - Exclude generated files

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

Is there any way, how to exclude android generated files (or manually specify excluded folders), from **Analyze -> Inspect Code** ?

Comment: Can you please tell how do you inspect code in android studio(gradle android studio project). Are there any plugins available. Can it be done using command line.

Comment: You can inspect code from Android Studio menu (Analyze > Inspect Code), from CLI you can go with Gradle Android Lint (`gradle lint`), but you cannot do the same Code Inspection from CLI as Android Studio (IntelliJ IDEA) can from GUI.

Comment: Is there any other tool available which can be operated from command line?

Comment: See http://www.sonarqube.org/ that is widely used and is able to give you reports from Continuous-Integration/Code-Quality analysis on CLI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found answer

Excluded folders won't be taken in account for **Code Analysis**

- Right-click on top-level element and go to **Open Module Settings**
- There you have listed single modules, select correct module
- In right column select folders to be excluded and either **right click -> exclude** or **button exclude above the file tree**
- In left column remove all leftover references to excluded directories from other groups than **Excluded Folders**

[image: Excluding folders]

Comment: Is there a way to do this on build.gradle?

Comment: I don't have any of this for Android Studio.  Is it because my project is wearable/mobile project?  https://www.dropbox.com/s/zezxtycckls0mel/Screenshot%202014-10-30%2018.04.37.png?dl=0

Comment: don't have it either, old answer

Answer (score 4):

Use a custom scope. After clicking Analyze > Inspect Code, from the Specify Inspection Scope dialog, click "..." after "Custom scope". Define a new scope. Recursively include `Android`, `app`, and whatever else is important. Then recursively exclude folders you don't want.

I like to put my generated code in the `build` folder and exclude it. (To get code in the `build` folder to be included in the build, include it in `app.gradle` in `android/sourceSets/main/java.srcDirs`.)

Comment: Just wanted to say that this works, whereas the accepted answer is outdated.

Comment: Just wanted to say currently this is recommended by android developers blog.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the [Gradle IDEA plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html):

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
    module {
        excludeDirs = [file("unwanted-directory-name")]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743242/how-do-i-get-android-studio-to-stop-returning-generated-code-in-search-results/32691872#32691872) answer:

You basically just create a custom scope with the following pattern: `!file:*intermediates*/&&!file:*generated*/&&!lib:*..*`

Hope this helps.