# How do I get Android Studio to stop returning generated code in search results?

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time I use `Search In Path` in Android Studio, I end up with generated code being returned as the first section of results.

I usually search for something in `*.java,*.xml`, and usually investigate the first few results before I realize I'm looking at `Generated Code`. Is there a way to omit the generated code results from being returned as part of the result list, while still allowing the search to read all of the *.java and *.xml files in my project?

I have a feeling this is something beyond ridiculously simple, but I just can't find the right button to toggle.

---

In the same vein, is it possible to ignore generated classes when loading files or types? I keep getting the generated `MyClass$$ViewInjector` classes appearing first in open files, and it's just annoying...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio : Exclude files in build folder from search result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937468/android-studio-exclude-files-in-build-folder-from-search-result)

Comment: Hear hear!  And to always put the generated code at the top, as if that's what most people are searching for!  Sigh.

Comment: @Travis you should really accept the answer...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore R.java fies in Find results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973939/ignore-r-java-fies-in-find-results)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write a custom search filter to weed out R.java files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682656/how-do-i-write-a-custom-search-filter-to-weed-out-r-java-files)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The way I've been doing to ignore generated classes in advanced search is adding `!file:*intermediates*/&&!file:*generated*/&&!lib:*..*` to a new Custom Scope, like this:

[image]

**14-October-2015 Update:** I have improved the pattern by also excluding the `!lib:*..*` from the search. Thanks.

Comment: @Gazta this configuration is stored in the `.idea/scopes/` folder. In order to set it up across different projects, you'll need to copy that file around. See also [this SO answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313946/can-i-share-settings-for-intellij-idea-across-different-projects)

Comment: there should be a global scope, I hope they add it soon.

Comment: Thank you! But databinding files are not excluded. Can you help me? Path:
app/build/generated/source/kapt/develDebug/de/XXXXX/YYYY/ZZZZ/databinding/FragmentDownloadBindingImpl.java << not excluded

Comment: It should be excluded since its path contains the `generated` string. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this in IntelliJ, haven't checked in Android Studio. But when you do find in path (via ctrl+shift+F) there's a "File name filter" section in the search popup which has a checkbox called "File masks" which you might be able to filter desired file types.

Comment: It generates .java files though, so it's not super helpful. It's gotten a lot better as of late, so it's not nearly as annoying as it used to be. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

For me, just to add to the answer, the scope `!file:*intermediates*/&&!file:*generated*/&&!file:*build*/&&!lib:*..*` worked even better!