# Using ButterKnife added some $$file to search result

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, butterknife

I added `Butterknife` to my project and when I want to search through project files with `Ctrl+shift+N` the result contains some junk file (`_$$ViewBinder` or `$blah blah`) Is it possible to filter this files?

[image: Search screen-shot contains $files]

Comment: Those classes are generated to perform the view look-ups and other method/resources/etc bindings. Have a look at that article https://medium.com/@lgvalle/how-butterknife-actually-works-85be0afbc5ab#.fx6gtuowh

Comment: @Nazik thanks for your suggestion. But I think it's possible to remove this file from search result. If you use Android Annotation this file doesn't appear in search result.

Comment: @Amir you can hide generates files from a complete search there : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32691872/2667946