# Open file shortcut not showing project files Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-3.0

One of my most used shortcuts in Android Studio is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> (open file).  It lets me easily open up any layout, class, interface, etc file in my project easily.

Lately I've noticed that the only files that show up in the list are auto-generated files like Daggers *_MemberInjector.java, and *_ProvidesXFactory.java files, but none of my actual project files.

It seems like they're missing more often then they are actually in the list.  How do I get them back for good?

Comment: Maybe you changed your keymap setting . . . you can check that setting as well.

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743242/how-do-i-get-android-studio-to-stop-returning-generated-code-in-search-results

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but I have two Android projects open in Android Studio. Project 1 is having the problem with shortcut, Project 2 - opens the dialog to navigate to class when I press Shift+⌘+o .

When I did "File" -> "Invalidate Caches..." -> "Invalidate and Restart", then the problem went to the other project. Now Project 1 can navigate to class with the keyboard shortcut, and in Project 2 the shortcut doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean this to provide a solution to the question at the top of this page? This reads like "Me too, and what I tried did not help either."