# How do I get Android Studio 3.5.3 to stop returning generated code in search results?

Tags: android-studio

This is not a duplicate of [How do I get Android Studio to stop returning generated code in search results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743242/how-do-i-get-android-studio-to-stop-returning-generated-code-in-search-results/32691872)

The just mention question is simalar and the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32691872/1815624 was good until i updated Android Studio to 3.5.3 (or at least now is when I noticed this issue)

One would use the `search scope` and set it to `!file:*intermediates*/&&!file:*generated*/` and the generated and intermediate files would be discluded from search results. I can not find where to set this any longer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the "scope" option was simply moved to under the search bar where I had not notice...

[image: Menu showing scope option]

from which you can add a "Custom" scope as desired...

[image]